# how can you tell a real e-mail from a fake?

Tags: email

I used to get emails from this guy possibly pretending to be a friend of mine (using an AIM account rather than his GMAIL one). Things were going OK with email tramsmisions but now everytime I send, they come back as MAILER DAEMON
is there any possible way to tell where those email originated from.....after I deleted the emails that went through?

Answer (score 0):

email information is stored in email's header. If you don't the the emails anymore, you won't be able to tell where did they come from.